# Testing nested dictionaries for a user input and retrieving directly related information

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested, dictionary-comprehension

I’m new to Python 3 and have been experimenting with Dictionaries but I’m having problems testing for a specific key and retrieving its related values from nested dictionaries.

I want a user defined input to be checked against nested dictionaries and if the user input is found I then want to collect the details for that item and add it to another dictionary.

E.g.

```
basketDict = {}
shopDict = {"Fruit": {"Apple": "2", "Banana": "3"},
             "Vegetables": {"Lettuce": "5", "Potato": "7"}}
userQuery = input("What food do you want to check for? ")
```

userQuery = "Apple"

Desired result:

```
basketDict = {"Fruit": {"Apple": "2"}}
```

I've attempted to use dictionary comprehension to form a new dictionary of only food items (Apple, Banana, Lettuce etc.) but keep running into issues when trying to collect the related category ("Fruit"/"Vegetable" and quantity information from the nested dictionaries.

Here's my (broken) code:

```
basketDict = {}
shopDict = {"Fruit": {"Apple": "2", "Banana": "3"},
             "Vegetables": {"Lettuce": "5", "Potato": "7"}}
shopCheck = []

userQuery = input("What food do you want to check for? ")
for category, food in shopDict.items():
    for each in food:
        shopCheck.append(each)

    if userQuery not in shopCheck:
        print("That's not available.")
    else:
        print(userQuery + " added to basket. ")
        basketDict[category] = [food]

print(basketDict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is enough for your requirements:

```
for category, food in shopDict.items():
    if userQuery in food:
        basketDict[category] = {userQuery: food[userQuery]}
```

But if you want to add new items to the basket, you should update it properly:

```
for category, food in shopDict.items():
    if userQuery in food:
        basketDict.update(
            {category: {**basketDict.get(category, {}),
                        **{userQuery: food[userQuery]}}}
        )
```

You want to merge the actual dictionary of the category (the basket's actual content) with the selected item's key-value.
Generally in python3 if you have 2 dictionaries this is the way to merge them into one:

```
d1 = {"one": 1, "two": 2}
d2 = {"three": 3}
merged = {**d1, **d2}  # {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
```

Because `**` is used to unpack the dictionary.

Good way to understand it is if you have a function definition with some arguments, then you can call the function with a dictionary that has the argument names as keys. But you have to unpack it, otherwise you would pass the dictionary as the parameter, and not its values.

```
d = {"one": 1, "two": 2}
def example(one, two):
    pass
```

`example(d)` would throw a TypeError, because it's missing the second positional argument, but `example(**d)` would work fine

Comment: This works wonderfully for my purpose. I am somewhat puzzled by the contents and structure of the basketDict.update() though - I'm not familiar with the '**' or structure of the contents within the (). 

Would you be able to provide an explanation or point me to resources where I can learn how it functions?

Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I made some changes to be more clear. Also, you don't have to use the method `update`, simply set the key's value: `basketDict[category] = {**basketDict.get(category, {}), **{userQuery: food[userQuery]}}`

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by creating a dictionary containing all the items you can buy, whether they're fruit or vegetables. Then I'd simply check if the required item is on that dictionary:

```
basketDict = {}
shopDict = {"Fruit": {"Apple": "2", "Banana": "3"},
             "Vegetables": {"Lettuce": "5", "Potato": "7"}}
allVals = {}

for k, subDict in shopDict.items():
    for k1, val in subDict.items():
        allVals[k1] = val


userQuery = input("What food do you want to check for? ")
if userQuery not in allVals.keys():
    print("That's not available.")
else:
    print(userQuery + " added to basket. ")
    basketDict[userQuery] = allVals[userQuery]

print(basketDict)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: Oops, sorry, I tested this with python2.7. I'll fix this!

Answer (score 0):

Probably there's a simpler way to do this, but I just fixed your code.
When I run your code, everything inside `shopDict` was going to `basketDict`. This is because you wasn't cleaning your `shopCheck` variable at each `for` iteration.
And there was a second mistake when adding the elements to `basketDict`. You need to add only the `food` element that match the `userQuery`. Here's the full fixed code:

```
basketDict = {}
shopDict = {"Fruit": {"Apple": "2", "Banana": "3"},
            "Vegetables": {"Lettuce": "5", "Potato": "7"}}

userQuery = input("What food do you want to check for? ")
for category, food in shopDict.items():
    shopCheck = []
    for each in food:
        shopCheck.append(each)

    if userQuery not in shopCheck:
        print("That's not available.")
    else:
        print(userQuery + " added to basket. ")
        basketDict[category] = {userQuery:food[userQuery]}

print(basketDict)
```

Comment: this too has indentation issues I guess

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I run this code and enter 'Apple', it erroneously produces, "That's not available." despite successfully adding it to the basketDict. Any ideas why?

Comment: @MHSalehi Actualy if you analyse the code carefully you will see that is not an error. Since the `shopDict` has two pair of  key-values (in this case category-food pairs), the outer `for` will be executed twice: one for the key "Fruit" and another for the key "Vegetables". That second iteration is generates that print because `Apple` indeed isn't present among the "Vegetable" values what is totaly right.